# Error "Unexpected end of input" en mi programa de javascript

Tags: javascript

Hola a todos tengo problemas con el siguiente código escrito en javascript. Si alguien me colabora por favor.

El error que obtengo es:

```
Error: Line 33: Unexpected end of input
```

Y mi código es:

```
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log("slider partner");
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    console.log(pathname);
    if ( pathname == "/realizzazione-siti-web-proba-slider/") {
      console.log(2222);
        jQuery.when(
            jQuery.getScript( "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.4.2/js/swiper.min.js" ),
            jQuery.Deferred(function( deferred ){
                jQuery( deferred.resolve );
            })
        ).done(function(){
          
          
          
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
  
  grabCursor: true,
  centeredSlides: true,
  slidesPerView: "auto",
  coverflowEffect: {
    rotate: 20,
    stretch: 0,
    depth: 350,
    modifier: 1,
    slideShadows: true
  },
  
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination"
  }
  });
});
```

Comment: ¿Este es todo tu código?¿Cuál es la línea 33 de tú código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta cerrar una vez más. Si la identacion fuese correcta, no tendrías ese problema.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
console.log("slider partner");
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
console.log(pathname);
if (pathname == "/realizzazione-siti-web-proba-slider/") {
    console.log(2222);
    jQuery.when(
        jQuery.getScript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.4.2/js/swiper.min.js"),
        jQuery.Deferred(function (deferred) {
            jQuery(deferred.resolve);
        })
    ).done(function () {
        var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
            grabCursor: true,
            centeredSlides: true,
            slidesPerView: "auto",
            coverflowEffect: {
                rotate: 20,
                stretch: 0,
                depth: 350,
                modifier: 1,
                slideShadows: true
            },
            pagination: {
                el: ".swiper-pagination"
            }
        }
        )
    }
    )
}
});
```

Comment: Segun el validador de codigo de esprima sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Entonces corrige tu publicación, y agrega todo el código. En 5 minutos borro esta respuesta. Además, indica la linea 33

Comment: Ese es todo el codigo

Comment: Seguro ?? Ahi respondi con todo ese codigo re-identado

Comment: Ahora si hermano. Eres un crack. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Utiliza bien la identacion, eso es solo cerrar las llaves { } y () además de ;
Quizas tu programa de edicion podría dar cuenta de eso, que usas ?

Comment: Tienes razon. Apenas estoy iniciando y tengo algunos problemas. Utilizo php storm

Comment: Que raro, debería tener incluido las correcciones a codigo. Yo uso Visual Studio Code, con extension agregada. A todo esto, recuerda marcar mi respuesta como la correcta, me ayuda mucho ;)